# Window.onload and ordering

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, I can't seem to understand the ordering of events.  When I load this in the browser, I get the alert before the first div renders and the .onclick event listener cannot find the translate_button element to attach to.  I thought because of the use of window.onload, my script would execute after the above html loaded.  Does this have to do with the inline javascript within the html?

```
<div id='MicrosoftTranslatorWidget' class='Dark' id='translate_button'></div><script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function(){{var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.charset='UTF-8';s.src=((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0)?'https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com':'http://www.microsofttranslator.com')+'/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**&ctf=True&ui=true&settings=Manual&languages=es,pt,fr,it,tr,zh-CHS,zh-CHT,ru,de,en';var p=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.documentElement;p.insertBefore(s,p.firstChild); }},0);</script>
<div class='disclaimer-link' id='disclaimer-link' style='display:none'>Disclaimer</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("translate_button");
    button.onclick = alert("lol");
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning function execution. If you want to assign actual function you need something like

```
button.onclick = function() { alert("lol"); }
```

Another thing - you have ID defined twice for the DIV. Remove one and use the one that remains.

Comment: I think you're right about 'translate_button' no longer existing, but after trying it using an id that is present in the html after the Bing script is run (found by inspecting element), it still isn't being found

Comment: Don't use 'translate_button', use 'MicrosoftTranslatorWidget' - apparently script needs it. Here's a small demo of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/ao05mmod/ (You may need to click [x] in the widget initially)

Comment: That seems to work but is there any way to work around needing to click the widget button twice in order to trigger it?